# getting started with augmented reality Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, augmented-reality

I'm planning to start an application comprises of augmented reality in android.

Proposed application should do the following :

1. Whenever user come across certain logo, he will capture that logo by using device's camera.
2. Then the captured image will undergo pattern-matching and will be compared with the predefined image present in the database.
3. Based on matching, certain action will take place(This is not the matter of concern as of now).

How do I start???

I came across the similar questions on SO, but haven't got any satisfactory info.

I had a glance at [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) but it says : *It has C++, C, Python and soon Java interfaces running on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac*.

As I'm using `Mono for Android`, it uses `C#` for development. So will `openCV` work in this scenario?

Also I'm relatively new to android development and just beginner when it comes to using `Mono for Android`.

I know I'm being bit unclear in this que, but I really don't have any idea about augmented reality so **any tutorial/book to start with in order to develop the app based on AR will be of great help.**

Comment: Links provided in similar questions are not for the beginners of AR. I want to start with the scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android ARToolkit](http://code.google.com/p/andar/) can be a good start point

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating people counting and identification using cameras and came across this thread.

From my limited knowledge, OpenCV seems to be widely used when it comes to image processing.

They even list it as one of the developer tools in the Microsoft Kinect SDK.

openCV is open source and there are several wrappers which will allow you to use it in a .Net environment.

One which lists compatibility with Mono and Monodoroid (Mono for Android) is [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV_for_Android) althought there is a small [license fee](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Commercial_License_Purchase) if the wrapper will be used in a commercial application.